# <apex:pagemessage> is not working

Tags: visualforce

> Position Name is mandatory in below code snippet, but when I don't enter anything and click save, record is getting saved with Position name as ID of that record and error is not thrown even if I have used `<apex:pageMessages>`. Can somebody please help?

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Positions__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Positions">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Positions__c.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Positions__c.Functional_Area__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Have you tried rerendering pagemessages it.

```
<apex:page standardController="Positions__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Positions">
            <apex:pageMessages id="myPGMSG"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Positions__c.Name}" required="true" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Positions__c.Functional_Area__c}" required="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" rerender="myPGMSG"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: yes I tried that, but it is still not working

Comment: Its working at my end? which browser you using?

Comment: Try setting required="true" for both fields?

Comment: I am using Chrome. On adding required =true, it is working fine, but if not added, it doesn't. I think what Anurag said above is correct. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you make this field empty and try to save it then Salesforce insert an Id value in this. If you want to make it mandatory then you need to create a controller, need to call controller method for save and throw an error when name field is empty.
You cannot do this, this is default functionality of Salesforce.